# jQuery setTimeout won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to compare two password fields and show a Popover if they don't match.

## HTML

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-6">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" required data-toggle="popover" title="Password Strength" value="" placeholder="Enter your password...">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-6">
    <label>Repeat Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passwordrep" id="passwordrep" value="" data-bind="popover" data-content="No match" placeholder="Confirm password...">
</div>
```

My jQuery Code works if i'm not using setTimeout. But i want to wait for a few seconds before showing the "no match" popover.

## JS

```
function showPopover(id){
  $(id).popover('show');
}

var x_timer;

$("body").delegate('#passwordrep', 'keyup', function(){
    clearTimeout(x_timer);

    if($(this).val() != $('#password').val()){
      x_timer = setTimeout(function(){showPopover(this);}, 1000);
    }
    else {
      $(this).popover('hide');
    }
});
```

Comment: I think your code does not work because `this` is not what you think it is in the closure. Be careful, properly set a variable outside the closure with `this`, and then use the variable.

Comment: Or use es6 arrow function feature

Comment: what kind of a title is this? it doesn't describe the real problem and also `jquery` doesn't have anything to do with any `setTimeout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` doesn't refers to element which invoked the event handler in the [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) argument. You can pass parameters to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) which will be available to the function

```
setTimeout(function(elem){
   showPopover(elem);
}, 1000, this);
```

Note: [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)  has been deprecated. It was superseded by the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method since jQuery 1.7,

---

You can also use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```
setTimeout((function(){
   showPopover(this);
}).bind(this), 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkPassword(elt1,elt2){
    return elt1.value()==elt2.value();
}
```

you can call it **on keyup**, you can add **if** to show some message